# Display a custom calculated cart item price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to calculate the price of a variable product in the cart. I want to multiply the product price with some custom cart item numerical value.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'func_change_product_price_cart', 10, 3 );
function func_change_product_price_cart($price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
    if (isset($cart_item['length'])){
        $price = $cart_item['length']*(price of variation);
        return $price;
    }

}
```

The price calculation doesn't work. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you overwriting `$price` ?

Comment: Ah! I can just do this? $new_price = $price*$cart_item['length']; return $new_price.

Comment: yes...exactly!!

Comment: Or even just `return $price*$cart_item['length'];` without the extra variable.

Comment: _Or even just return..._ This is more elegant of course @Dave

Comment: When I try both solutions above the price in the cart displays as 0 tho.

Comment: _the price in the cart displays as 0..._ `var_dump` `$price, $cart_item` to see what is in there before calculating

Comment: Where do I put the var_dump?

Comment: The price displayed might be 0 because $price is a string? echo var_dump($price); displays this: string(124) "KR50.00". Does Woocommerce set he price to 0 by default if there is an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$price` argument in this hook **is the formatted product item price**, then you need **the raw price** instead to make it work on your custom calculation. Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_cart_item_price', 10, 3 );
function change_cart_item_price( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if ( WC()->cart->display_prices_including_tax() ) {
        $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
    } else {
        $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'] );
    }

    if ( isset($cart_item['length']) ) {
        $price = wc_price( $product_price * $cart_item['length'] );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: It works! :D Thank you :) Is there also a filter to change the cart totals by any chance?

Comment: Is it possible to set the variation price of the cart item to the same as the new $price?

Comment: Something like this? $cart_item['data']->set_price = $price;  So the total price also gets updated in the cart.